# Plot Spectrogram with Python

Tags: python, audio, jupyter-notebook, spectrogram

I want to plot a spectrogam like the image below.

I tried the following, but I got something strange:

```
f, t, Sxx = spectrogram(sound, sample_rate)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)
plt.ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylim(top=500)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.show()
```

Perhaps I need to change `pcolormesh` to something else, can you help me with that?

Thanks a lot!

**What I want:**

[image]

**What I got:**
[image]

Comment: `I got something strange:` is pretty subjective what were you expecting?

Comment: Define "strange". Looks like a spectrogram to me.

Comment: You both are correct, I have updated the question. I want to achieve the first one, but I got the black one instead. Thanks!